# How to using wp_set_current_user in own project?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried using `wp_set_current_user` function in my project to automatically log in to WordPress from my project. The code is shown below:

```
$q = mysql_query("select * from user where email='$email' and password='$password'");

if (mysql_num_rows($q) == 1) {
   require_once 'wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php';    
   $user_id = 5;

   wp_set_current_user( $user_id, "bookmark" );
   wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
   do_action( 'wp_login', "bookmark" );
}
```

I have followed instructions from [official docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_current_user#Examples).

The code above doesn't work and I'm not sure that I wrote the code properly.

Comment: Is it giving you an error ? And don't use `mysql` as it is deprecated.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner I got blank page after i implemented it. I need mysql syntax, because i want to execute automatically log in wordpress after i have logged in from my own login form.

Comment: make sure error reporting 'on' and check if there is any error

Comment: @crayon found any way?
please help me too

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_singon` function:

```
$creds[‘user_login’] = $first_name;

// ACCOUNT PASSWORD TO USE

$creds[‘user_password’] = $password;
$creds[‘remember’] = true;
$autologin_user = wp_signon($creds, false);

if (!is_wp_error($autologin_user))
{
$home_url = get_home_url() . ” / ? reg = true”;
wp_redirect($home_url);
}
```

here is official link: [LINK](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon)

Comment: I got error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined function do_action_ref_array(). How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a wordpress user with id 5 and username "bookmark" .
   then try this code.

```
 $user_id =5;
 $current_user = new WP_User( $user_id, "bookmark" );
 setup_userdata( $current_user->ID );
```